# Write a query to display the name of the department that has the maximum staff count order by department name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select max(count(department_id)) 
from staff
group by department_id
```

```
ERROR at line 4:                                                                
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

```
Select department_name 
from staff s 
  inner join department d on s.department_id=d.department_id 
having count(s.department_id) in (Select max(count(department_id)) 
                                  from staff) group by department_id
```

--- Expected output ---

````
 DEPARTMENT_NAME
------------------------------
SE

```none
---Difference in Output---
(select max(count(department_id)) from staff)group by departmentDEPARTMENT_idNAME 
                                                      *------------------------------ 
SERROR at line 4: 
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined 

 Summary of tests
+------------------------------+
| 2 tests run / 0 test passed  |
+------------------------------+
````

Comment: seems you have common column `department_name` for `department` and `staff` tables. To remove the error qualify `department_name` with an alias `s` or `d`.

Answer (score 0):

**Query:**

```
select dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME, count(dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME) as staff_count from 
hr.departments dept, hr.employees emp
where dept.DEPARTMENT_ID=emp.DEPARTMENT_ID(+)
group by dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME
order by count(dept.DEPARTMENT_NAME) desc 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

You can run the above query in https://livesql.oracle.com/

And the for more information on Fetch can be found on link
    https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1

Answer (score 0):

```
 select department_id, count(*) from staff group by department_id
 having count(*) = (select max(count(*)) 
                    from staff group by  department_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

On multiple places, You missed alias and I have added it as following:

```
SELECT
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME -- ADDED ALIAS HERE
FROM
    STAFF S
    INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON S.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY
    D.DEPARTMENT_ID -- ADDED ALIAS HERE
HAVING
    COUNT(S.DEPARTMENT_ID) IN (
        SELECT
            MAX(COUNT(DEPARTMENT_ID))
        FROM
            STAFF
    );
```

Also, You can achieve the same result using the following query:

```
SELECT
    D.DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM
    DEPARTMENT D
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            S.DEPARTMENT_ID,
            COUNT(1)
        FROM
            STAFF S
        ORDER BY
            2 DESC
        FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
    ) S ON S.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

check it out

```
select department_name from (select d.department_name,count(s.staff_id) as c from department d join staff s on d.department_id=s.department_id
group by d.department_name) mx where c=(select max(count(staff_id)) from staff group by department_id) order by department_name;
```

Comment: Could you explain your code a bit so we could understand what to check out in your code?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT department_name
FROM department
WHERE department_id IN
    (SELECT department_id
     FROM staff
     HAVING COUNT(department_id) IN
       (SELECT MAX(COUNT(department_id))
        FROM staff
        GROUP BY department_id)
     GROUP BY department_id);
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. Care to explain?